# PHP Session not unsetting

Tags: php, session

My PHP session seems to not be unsetting. When I return to the home page after clicking logout, if I refresh the page again then it seems to log me back in.. as if the session never actually ended. The same occurs if I leave the page and re-visit it. Here is my logout.php page:

```
<?php

// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();

header("Location: index.php");

?>
```

I really have no idea why it's doing this, any help would DEFINITELY be appreicated. If you need anymore information I'd be happy to provide some. Thanks!

Comment: Call `session_unset()` before `session_destroy()`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php lately, I found actually reading the manual pages for the functions I use to be very interesting. Even functions I was used to I could learn new things. For now, it's written clearly in the first few paragraphs that you must unset the session for it to be truly destroyed :)

Comment: @Félix Gagnon-Grenier: OP uses the exact code from documentation. You may also found interesting not only reading the documentation but the questions!

Comment: Yeah, I followed the code from the documentation. I have no idea why it doesn't work... but it seems to be an issue with my chrome at the moment because upon downloading Firefox and testing it on that it works! Although, having said that, it doesn't work on Chrome on my phone so I've no idea as to what's going on.

Comment: Chrome != firefox != mobile  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code in your logout.php

```
session_start(); 
unset($_SESSION['var_name']); //  delete just the session of va_name data
session_destroy(); // delete ALL session info/Data.
```